# does the use of try and except and if else statements in python is same?

Tags: python

can we use same thing with try except and if else or not?

I tried to use the try except and if else statements separately but it is not meeting certain conditions?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: if/else is completely different to try/except. Have you tried:- https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/

Answer (score 1):

In Python, try and except statement has use for error handling. The `try` statement allows you to test a code for errors and The `except` allows you to handle the error.
example:

```
try:
   # this code may cause an error
except some_Error:
   # this code will handle some_Error
```

in the other hand if and else statement, a block of code to be executed if a condition is true or other wise will to another task.

```
if (condition):
  # execute this code
else:
  # execute this code
```

in try and except statement, 1st code will try to execute but if there is an error of specific type it will do the alternative code to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

Try:Except blocks are for controlling errors in your code. Let's say you try and print a variable that doesn't exist, then you would get a NameError, which you could build an exception.

```
try:
  print(x)
except NameError:
  print("Variable x is not defined")
except:
  print("Something else went wrong")
```

IF:THEN:ELSE statements are used for controlling conditionals. If this condition is true then execute this block of code, else execute this block of code. You can build complex if:then:else statements to help minimize errors through input checks and such but that is not their primary purpose.

Answer (score 0):

No! there is a bit difference between both as the code of if else can be used for multiple conditions using elif inside but the same cant be done with try and except.